# Get first N items with check key value count from python list

Tags: python, list

There is an sample list.

```
[('100', '10', 9),
 ('108', '18', 5),
 ('100', '11', 5),
 ('102', '12', 4),
 ('100', '22', 4),
 ('102', '20', 3),
 ('104', '15', 3),
 ('100', '21', 3),
 ('108', '25', 3)]
```

First values of lists are id `('100','108','100','102',....)`, second values are results `('10','18','11','12',.....)` and third values are count of results `(9,5,5,4,...)`

For example, I want to get first 6 results which are having the biggest counts,however for an unique id, it has **MAXIMUM** 2 value.

Example answer should  be  `['10','18','11','12','20','15']`

```
 ('100', '10', 9) ------>  Ok,first value of key '100' 
 ('108', '18', 5) ------>  Ok,first value of key '108'
 ('100', '11', 5) ------> Ok,second value of key '100'
 ('102', '12', 4) ------> Ok, first value of key '102'
 ('100', '22', 4) ------> No,key '100' has 2 result.
 ('102', '20', 3) ------> Ok,second value of key '102'
 ('104', '15', 3) ------> Ok,first value of key '104' --> FINISH 6 values is getting
```

***In my real project** I want to get first 50 biggest result and for an unique id I want to get **MAXIMUM** 5 results. How to can I achieve this?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: To create this list I write 500 rows, however my brain stop for this situation now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do iterate over the list of tuples (`l` here), and keep a count of how many times the first element in the tuples has appeared, appending the tuples to a list as long as the first item has appeared less than `N` times:

```
N = 2
max_len = 6
s = dict()
out = []
c = 0
for i, *j in l:
    s.setdefault(i, 0)
    if s[i] < N and c < max_len:
        s[i] += 1
        out.append((i,*j))
        c += 1
```

---

```
print(out)

[('100', '10', 9),
 ('108', '18', 5),
 ('100', '11', 5),
 ('102', '12', 4),
 ('102', '20', 3),
 ('104', '15', 3),
 ('108', '25', 3)]
```

---

Input list -

```
l = [('100', '10', 9),
 ('108', '18', 5),
 ('100', '11', 5),
 ('102', '12', 4),
 ('100', '22', 4),
 ('102', '20', 3),
 ('104', '15', 3),
 ('100', '21', 3),
 ('108', '25', 3)]
```

Comment: should also meet constraint of max results returned, in this case it is 6

Comment: I think it should be ok now, that is IIUC the rest @aws_apprentice

Comment: only I  change c < max_len + 1 to c < max_len. Because There is 7 seven answer now in your answer. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Oops, true @EmreBAY :)

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a function if you want to change the parameters later:

```
lst = [('100', '10', 9),
 ('108', '18', 5),
 ('100', '11', 5),
 ('102', '12', 4),
 ('100', '22', 4),
 ('102', '20', 3),
 ('104', '15', 3),
 ('100', '21', 3),
 ('108', '25', 3)]



def func(lst, max_val, first_n_results):
    # ensure sorted by final col
    sorted_list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
    counts = {i:0 for i in set([l[0] for l in sorted_list])}
    for item in sorted_list:
        counts[item[0]] += 1
        if counts[item[0]] > max_val:
            sorted_list.remove(item)

    first_n = sorted_list[:first_n_results]
    return [i[1] for i in first_n]
```

Input:

```
func(lst, 2, 6)
```

Output:

```
['10', '18', '11', '12', '20', '15']
```